# AngularJS Filter exception of objects

Tags: angularjs, filter

I use an AngularJS filter which looks like this:

```
ng-repeat="myObject in myObjects | filter:myScopeVar"
```

and it works fine. myObject can look like this

```
myObject.start = '2016-02-29';
myObject.containerType.value = 'SERVICE'
...
```

or

```
myObject.start = '2016-02-29';
myObject.containerType.value = 'NIGHT_SERVICE'
...
```

or

```
myObject.start = '2016-02-29';
myObject.containerType.value = 'PADDING'
...
```

Objects with the containerType 'PADDING' should never be filtered. Also if myObject.containerType.value = 'SERVICE' than only the SERVICE- objects should be filtered and not also the 'NIGHT_SERVICE' ones.

Is there a way of doing this without writing a filter function?
The filtering should be very performant because this is very critical.

Comment: I don't understand the last part could you correct your tense/english in general  After your last snippet. BTW why do you want to avoid using a filter function?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a filter function which works fine and looks like this:

```
function myFilter() {
        return function( item ) {
            if(vm.containerTypeFilter == '' || vm.containerTypeFilter == null) {
                return true;
            } else if(item.containerType == vm.containerTypeFilter || item.containerType == 'PADDING') {
                return true; 
            }
            return false;
          };
    }
```